# How to optimize big table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a Table with 2 Columns, one of them is unique...In this table i have 112 000 000 rows...select and delete queries for single row take over 60 second...is this normal and is there any way to decrease execution time?

Comment: Either you're running the query on a 1MHz microcontroller reading data from a 5.25" floppy disk over a 300cps modem connection or you *really* dislike indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Post your DDL.

Typically you want to make sure you have appropriate indexing.

Review your execution plan.

The size of table should be irrelevant for single row deletes with an appropriate choice of index.

Comment: @user1189407 "Post your DDL" should be interpreted as running "DESC yourtablename" or even better "SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtablename" against the database and posting the output

Answer (score 0):

There might be many reasons, we need for information:

1. Types of the columns - are they varchar, text, int ?
2. Query you try to invoke
3. use EXPLAIN Query and copy paste the result
4. Do you have any indexes ?

Most probably you do not have proper indexes. If you do have them, it might be the case that they are not used. For example, if you have id, varchar and you try to do select * from table where varchar LIKE '%something%' then your index on varchar column cannot be used. That is why we need result of explain.